# Callback or listen from child to parent in UI Router, Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

As a simple example of the type of pattern I am looking for, I have a list component that has a "list item chosen" event. I do not want to provide the actual action for this event inside that component itself. Instead I want the owning component to provide it. As I understand it, this is a pretty standard component pattern as it enforces separation of duties and encourages re-use (as you could use the same list component in another context where the selection results in a different action).

In UI Router for AngularJS, this was easily achieved by using a template instead of just referencing the component and passing a callback function in there, like this:

```
            .state('nav.clientHeader.clientList',{
            template: '<client-list clients="$ctrl.clients" ' +
            'onClick="$ctrl.loadClient"></client-list>',
            url: '/list'
        })
```

My question is, how is this achieved in UI Rotuer 2, for Angular 2+? The new standard way to do callbacks in Angular 2+ is to use the @Output decoration to set up an emit/listen pattern between parent and child. But it looks like UI Router 2 isn't able to establish an @Output binding? https://github.com/ui-router/angular/issues/138 - is that a corrent reading of that issue, or is it talking about something else?

I see answers to similar issues in the main Angular Router suggest using a service to communicate between the two components but this seems like a crazy approach for something as simple as an onClick, especially given Angular actually has the correct pattern available to it via @Output.

Comment: There is no UI-router in angular 2+, please read this https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: If you follow the issue I linked you will see it is the github for UI Router for Angular 2+. The main webpage is here https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/. Angular team went with their own internal solution but the UI Router team plowed on and have a 2+ solution. It looks like both the official router and UI Router have this problem but I am solely concerned with UI Router

Comment: Angular 2+ has an own router-module which I strongly recommend you to use as it is the standard provided from the Angular team itself and you will find much more information on it on the web.

Comment: I am obviously aware of that Phil. I am upgrading a project that already uses UI Router so UI Router is the logical choice. The official router has its own issues and in general UI Router is more capable. Either way, it looks like the official router has the same issue with binding to @Output.